Is $\mathcal{O}_P(F)$ always a discrete valuation ring?
In Fulton's text Algebraic Curves, we have the following:

By sections 2.4 and 2.5, $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ is local, noetherian, a domain but not a field, and its maximal ring is principal. [So $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ is always a discrete valuation ring?]

By section 3.2, theorem 1, a point $P$ of $F$ is simple $\iff \mathcal{O}_P(F)$ is a discrete valuation ring. [So there must be cases when $\mathcal{O}_P(F)$ isn't a discrete valuation ring]


I think I must have missed something, but 1 would imply that all points are always simple and that is not the case. Can somebody point out where the error is?

Let's go through and see what's in the book. (Quick notational note for other readers: Fulton uses $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ for the more usual $\mathcal{O}_{V,P}$, the local ring of $V$ at $P$.)
Section 2.4
$V$ is assumed to be a nonempty variety in $\Bbb A^n$, and under this assumption, $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ is shown to be a Noetherian local domain in proposition 3.
Section 2.5
Proposition 4 shows that for a domain which is not a field, being a local noetherian domain with principal maximal ideal is equivalent to the existence of an irreducible element $t$ so that every element can be written $ut^n$ for $n$ a non-negative integer and $u$ a unit. (Equivalently, a noetherian local domain which is not a field with principal maximal ideal is a DVR.)
Section 3.2
Theorem 1 shows that $P$ is a simple point of a plane curve $F$ iff $\mathcal{O}_P(F)$ is a DVR and gives a selection of uniformizers.
What you missed
There is no claim as to when a point $P$ on a variety $V$ has the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ principal (if you think there is, please add a comment here or edit your post). For instance, if $V$ is of dimension $>1$, then there's no way for the maximal ideal $m$ of $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ to be principal, since the Krull dimension of $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ is equal to the dimension of $V$ at $P$, which is less than or equal to $\dim_k m/m^2$, which is equal to the minimum cardinality of a generating set for $m$ by Nakayama. There's also no claim that the maximal ideal $m$ of $\mathcal{O}_P(V)$ is always principal if $V$ is a curve, which is good, since that's not true - consider for instance $V$ as the curve cut out by $y^2-x^3-x^2$ and $P$ as the origin: both partial derivatives $-3x^2-2x$ and $2y$ vanish at the origin.
